# Can python read information from a text file and use it to validate a users input?

Tags: python, validation, variables, authentication, passwords

I already have a file with names of people and their name followed by a semicolon, e.g.:

> username:password

When the new program is run, the question if the user exists is asked, and they have to input their username and password. I want to make sure that they do exist, so how can I make the username and password into separate variables (without the colon) in order to compare the user's input and username in the .txt document ? (acting as a validation)

Comment: *"Can python read information from a text file and use it to validate a users input?"* - yes. But you'll need to tell it how to do that. Bear in mind that you should never store passwords in plain text, though - read up on salting and hashing.

Comment: @intboolstring - I have tried to make python read the text file and made it recognise the letters and numbers. Of course, it couldn't, as it has a colon in the middle. However, when I used the .replace() function, it still does not seem to work...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - is there a method. If so, can you link it to me or if you can, can you explain it?

Comment: Please, show us what you have wrote so far. Probably you simply need to read a line from the file, and split it on the first colon character.

Comment: Why would you use `replace`?! The *"method"* is: 1. Read the file. 2. Parse its content. 3. Use that data. And we don't do ASAP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I thought that it could be a method to make the words into 2 separate variables, at that time. Thanks for the help anyway, the response for me was quite fast (in my opinion)

Comment: @mnencia - the New edit is above the comments...just now

Comment: Don't change the question once you have answers, particularly not if you're going to claim the answerer's code as *"what I have managed to create so far"*. You still haven't told us what the *problem* with that you've written is, anyway; what debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question, you want to break the string "username:password" into two separate strings.  The way to do that is to use the split method to break the string into separate parts give a delimiter.  For example:

```
mystring = 'username:password'
splitstring = mystring.split(':') # this breaks it into a two element array
u = splitstring[0]
p = splitstring[1]
```

Hopefully this helps.  Please note however, as jonrsharpe points out in the comment above, you should never store credentials in a plain text file for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @jelliott, it was very helpful. How may this be used to work in a text file? Is it possible to retrieve information from a .txt file and make into variables?

Comment: @KarthikPonniah Certainly.  To parse the text file you'll have to know something of it's format.  For example, if it is comma-delimited or tab-delimited, etc.  You can start by reading in all lines of the text file like so:  `with open('file.txt') as f:  lines = f.readlines() ` then split each line up accordingly.